# gas fireplace main burner wont light but pilot will light

Tags: gas, fireplace

gas fireplace has switch on side of frame and it looks like a millivolt switch which goes down to gas valve and also a plug which I beleives runs the fan. Now when I depress the pilot switch the pilot lights then I hold down for a minute then when I let up to turn it to on the flame goes out.

Comment: If the pilot goes out when you stop pressing the gas override then either the thermocouple is bad or not in the flame enough.  The copper end that sticks into the flame actually generates the millivolts.  If there are no millivolts getting back to the gas valve it shuts the gas off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If @Tyson 's comment doesn't help you, then the make/model of the burner and perhaps a picture of the pilot light area would help.

Comment: In addition to @Tyson's very apt comment, there is also the chance of a control valve malfunction, but replacing the thermocouple is the cheapest/easiest initial troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can clean up the thermocouple with some fine sandpaper if you can get to the thermocouple 
It worked on my gas fireplace

Comment: Good idea: worth a shot until you can get a new thermocouple.